# Getting weird output in c with structures

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and just doing homework, thing is, I cant figure out why this the choice "Visualizar platos del dia" outputs weird symbols and not the things that I've input in with the cargar structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

struct platos{
    char aperitivo[40];
    char plato1[40];
    char plato2[40];
    char postre[40];
    char bebida1[40];
    char bebida2[40];
    char bebida3[40];
};

void cargar(struct platos a);
void vis(struct platos a);
void emit(struct platos a);

int main(){
    int a=0, b=0;
    struct platos plato;
do{
    printf("Bienvenido a restaurante 'Senior bigotes'\n\n");
    printf("1:Cargar platos del dia\n");
    printf("2:VIsualizar platos del dia\n");
    printf("3:Emitir comanda y factura\n");
    printf("4:Salir\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    switch(a){
        case 1: cargar(plato);
        break;
        case 2: vis(plato);
        break;
        case 3: emit(plato);
        break;    
        case 4: 
         b++;
        break;    
    }
    
    }while(b<1);

  return 0;
}

void cargar(struct platos a){
    printf("Ingrese aperitivo\n");
    __fpurge(stdin); 
    gets(a.aperitivo);
    printf("Ingrese plato 1\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.plato1);
    printf("Ingrese plato 2\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.plato2);
    printf("Ingrese postre\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.postre);
    printf("Ingrese bebida 1\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.bebida1);
    printf("Ingrese bebida 2\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.bebida2);
    printf("Ingrese bebida 2\n");
    __fpurge(stdin);
    gets(a.bebida3);
}


void vis(struct platos a){
    printf("\nAperitivo: %s", a.aperitivo);
    printf("\nPlato 1: %s", a.plato1);
    printf("\nPlato 2: %s", a.plato2);
    printf("\nPostre: %s", a.postre);
    printf("\nBebidas: %s | %s | %s\n", a.bebida1, a.bebida2, a.bebida3);
    int c = getchar();
}

void emit(struct platos a){
    printf("\nAperitivo: %s $10", a.aperitivo);
    printf("\nPlato 1: %s $25", a.plato1);
    printf("\nPlato 2: %s $35", a.plato2);
    printf("\nPostre: %s $20", a.postre);
    printf("\nBebidas: %s | %s | %s $15\n", a.bebida1, a.bebida2, a.bebida3);
    printf("Total: $105");
    int c = getchar();
}
```

I'm using manjaro btw with visual code. I asked the teacher and he wants me to debug the code but Idk how to do that in visual code. Any help?

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. `gets()` is vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: I don't have a file to receive the stream from, how do I implement that fgets into the code?

Comment: @ThaielAnaya: use `stdin` -- fgets from `stdin` is the same as `gets`, except it takes a buffer size so won't overflow the buffer.

Comment: ThaielAnaya, have covered that in my answer, the stream you need to use is `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean Visual Studio Code, it has a `Run` menu item that contains the the debugging items, such as `Toggle Breakpoint` and `Start Debugging`.

The first can be used on the statement you want to start debugging with, and the second to start running your code. Once the breakpoint is hit, there should be a small panel on the screen somewhere with controls for continue, step over, step into, and so on:

[image]

If you hover over those controls, it should also show you the equivalent keyboard commands you can use.

---

However, you should be aware that, for your *immediate* problem, structures are passed by *value* in C, not by reference. That means that the `cargar` function gets a *copy* of `plato` and populates the fields *of that copy*.

Then that copy is thrown away when returning from `cargar`, leaving the original `plato` with the arbitrary field it was given at creation time. So, when that is subsequently passed to `vis` or `emit`, you won't see the data you entered.

The easiest solution is probably to pass a pointer (`&plato`) to `cargar`, and use `->` rather than `.` to access the fields within that function. In other words, something like (see notes below as to why I'm using `fgets()`):

```c
switch (a) {
    case 1: cargar(&plato); break;
```

and

```c
void cargar(struct platos const *a_ptr){
    printf("Ingrese aperitivo\n");
    __fpurge(stdin); 
    fgets(a_ptr->aperitivo, sizeof(a_ptr->aperitivo), stdin);

    // And so on for the other fields ...
```

That particular `const` before `*a_ptr` applies to the pointer value itself rather than the value "behind" the pointer. You *need* to be able to change the value since that's the whole purpose of the function.

However, I'd also do something similar for `vis()` and `emit()` so as to not be copying large structures around but I'd use (for example):

```c
void vis(const struct platos const *plato) {
```

to make it clear neither the pointer nor the *value behind the pointer* is expected to change.

---

And, as others have mentioned in comments, you should use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`, there is no way to use the latter safely. If you want to know how to use it for user input, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

It should be an indication of how bad `gets()` is considered that it's actually been deprecated and removed from the standard.